# VBA Timezone issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have set up a script to populate UTC and Beijing when EST is entered it works fine.

```
isDst = isdaydat(CDate(Me.dtefrm.Value))

varest = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Me.estfrm.Value, "hh:mm:ss")

Me.estfrm.Value = varest
If isDst = True Then
    ut = CDate(varest)
    ut = DateAdd("h", 4, ut)
    ut = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(ut, "hh:mm:ss")
    Me.utcfrm.Value = ut
    bt = CDate(ut)
    bt = DateAdd("h", 8, bt)
    bt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(bt, "hh:mm:ss")
    Me.beifrm.Value = bt

    Else

    ut = CDate(varest)
    ut = DateAdd("h", 5, ut)
    ut = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(ut, "hh:mm:ss")
    Me.utcfrm.Value = ut
    bt = CDate(ut)
    bt = DateAdd("h", 8, bt)
    bt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(bt, "hh:mm:ss")
    Me.beifrm.Value = bt

End If
```

However, when I try to modify this to calculate EST and Beijing when UTC is given, I run into an error. I wonder if it has to do with the fact that I'm subtracting from UTC instead of adding to EST and I know excel freaks out with negative time values. When I did this on columns, I would use the Mod function but when I try to insert a worksheet Mod function it doesn't seem to show up in the intellisense.

```
isDst = isdaydat(CDate(Me.dtefrm.Value))

varutc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Me.utcfrm.Value, "hh:mm:ss")

Me.utcfrm.Value = varutc

If isDst = True Then
    et = CDate(varutc)
    et = DateAdd("h", -4, et)
    et = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(et, "hh:mm:ss")
    Me.estfrm.Value = et
    bt = CDate(varutc)
    bt = DateAdd("h", 8, bt)
    bt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(bt, "hh:mm:ss")
    Me.beifrm.Value = bt

    Else

    et = CDate(varutc)
    et = DateAdd("h", -5, ut)
    et = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(et, "hh:mm:ss")
    Me.estfrm.Value = et
    bt = CDate(varutc)
    bt = DateAdd("h", 8, bt)
    bt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(bt, "hh:mm:ss")
    Me.beifrm.Value = bt

End If
```

When I run this and try to enter time into the UTC box, I get `Runtime error "5" invalid procedure or argument` and when I debug it goes to the line

`et = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(et, "hh:mm:ss")`

in the second routine, I posted above.

I'm pretty sure this has to do with negative value. Help!

Comment: The Mod function in VBA has a different syntax from the corresponding worksheet function. It's simply `m = 105 Mod 10`, where m will be 5.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would suggest changing all occurrences of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Text` to `Format` (to use a [VBA function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) instead of a worksheet function).  The existing parameters should be fine as-is.

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Text` and `Format` both return strings (text) -- not dates, and therefore can be used to *display* dates but not to do calculations with them.

If you're not declaring your variables, you should be.  You can ensure that none are missed by adding a line `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.

A simplified version of your code:

```
Dim isDST As Boolean, varUTC As Date

isDST = isdaydat(CDate(Me.dteFrm.Value))
varUTC = CDate(Me.utcFrm.Value)

Me.utcFrm.Value = Format(varUTC, "hh:mm:ss")
Me.estFrm.Value = Format(DateAdd("h", IIf(isDST, -4, -5), varUTC), "hh:mm:ss")
Me.beiFrm.Value = Format(DateAdd("h", 8, varUTC), "hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your code but presumed that you have a user form with text boxes for the different times. Proceeding from that idea I thought that you shouldn't have a problem with negative numbers unless you took a wrong approach. In principle, you should calculate date/times, not merely times, because if you don't you can't accommodate the different dates you must invariably countenance if you compare Beijing time with EST. Therefore my code below takes any time you might enter, adds the current day to it, converts the result to UTC and then converts UTC to the target times. The default is the computer's time.

The code below should be pasted into the code sheet of a userform.

```
Option Explicit

    ' In the TbxUTC's Tag property:-
    ' enter a positive or negative value indicating the time difference
    ' between your computer's time and UCT (8 = China time)

    ' In the TbxBEI and TbxEST's Tag properties:-
    ' enter a positive or negative value indicating the time difference
    ' between the named time zone and UCT (Beijing +8, EST -5)

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' 06 Jan 2018
    SetTime
End Sub

Private Sub TbxUTC_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' 06 Jan 2018
    Cancel = Not SetTime(Me.ActiveControl)
End Sub

Private Sub TbxBEI_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' 06 Jan 2018
    Cancel = Not SetTime(Me.ActiveControl)
End Sub

Private Sub TbxEST_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' 06 Jan 2018
    Cancel = Not SetTime(Me.ActiveControl)
End Sub

Private Function SetTime(Optional Ctl As MSForms.TextBox) As Boolean
    ' 06 Jan 2018
    ' return Not True if an invalid date was entered

    ' set the format in which to display the time (date):-
    Const TimeFormat As String = "HH:mm:ss (ddd)"

    Dim Local_Utc As Integer                    ' computer time : UTC
    Dim Bei_Utc As Integer                      ' Beijing time : UTC (= +8)
    Dim Est_Utc As Integer                      ' EST : UTC (= -5)
    Dim UTC, EST, BEI
    Dim Tmp As String, n As Integer

    Local_Utc = TbxUTC.Tag                      ' Set in Tag property:-
    Bei_Utc = TbxBEI.Tag
    Est_Utc = TbxEST.Tag

    If Ctl Is Nothing Then                      ' upon initialisation
        ' reset time to computer time
        UTC = Now() - (Local_Utc / 24)
    Else
        Tmp = Ctl.Text
        n = InStr(Tmp, "(")
        If n Then Tmp = Left(Tmp, n - 1)
        UTC = Trim(Tmp)
        If IsDate(UTC) Then
            UTC = CDate(UTC)
            If Int(UTC) = 0 Then UTC = UTC + CLng(Date)
            If Not (Ctl Is TbxUTC) Then UTC = UTC - (Val(Ctl.Tag) / 24)
        Else
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid time.", _
                   vbExclamation, "Invalid time/date format"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    TbxUTC.Text = Format(UTC, TimeFormat)
    TbxBEI.Text = Format(UTC + (Bei_Utc / 24), TimeFormat)
    TbxEST.Text = Format(UTC + (Est_Utc / 24), TimeFormat)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    SetTime = True
End Function
```

The userform must have three text boxes named "TbxUTC", TbxBEI" and "TbxEST". The `Tag` properties of these text boxes must show the time difference between the named time zone and UTC. In the case of TbxUTC that value should be zero but I used the Tag to hold the time difference between your computer time and UTC instead.

When the form starts up the current (computer) time will be shown. You can then enter another time in any of the 3 text boxes and the code will fill the other two with the matching time in the other zones.

Comment: My computer happens to be on EST, should I set the TbxEST tag to 0, TbxUTC tag to +5 and Tbx to +13?

Comment: Why do I need to reference my computers time? Maybe I should give more context. I need to enter a large number of text messages data into a worksheet. So a column for the time stamp, a column for the date etc. Some of the messages have timestamps in UTC, some in EST some in Beijing. I would to have a form where whichever of the three timezones the timestamp belongs to, the other two boxes populate with the correct equivalent time for those zones. I have a function that determines whether on the date of the message was one on which DST was in effect or not, thus is utc is is +5 or +4/

Comment: UTC is the base. Therefore TbxEST.Tag = -5, TbxBEI.Tag = 8. TbxUTC.Tag has your computer's time, meaning -5. Change both to accommodate DST. The computer time is only used to populate the text boxes on start-up. After that you can enter a time in any of the boxes and have the other two synced as you require. Remember that the system is based on 24-hour time expressions. Eventually, you link the calculation directly to your worksheet. The important thing is the method which is quite different from your original approach.

Comment: As an after thought, consider parsing the message text before or after import into Excel to extract date and time automatically, then write code to apply the rules by which you decide the time zone and, finally, apply the conversion you now have. The effort of parsing the text can't be greater than what you already invested in creation of the user form. You might do in seconds what now takes you probably many hours.